# Pivot multiple values while keep same name column but different value columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this (This issue has been solved, I have to removed the datasets since it is kinda of sensitive)

My current code is :

```
ea2<-ea%>%
  select("ea_no","ea_actual","incidence_cases2012","incidence_cases2013","incidence_cases2014","incidence_cases2016","cumulative_incidence_2014","cumulative_incidence_2016")%>%
    pivot_longer(
    cols = c("incidence_cases2012","incidence_cases2013","incidence_cases2014","incidence_cases2016","cumulative_incidence_2014"),
    names_to = "year",
    values_to ="incidence_cases"
  )%>%
  mutate(year=str_sub(year, 16,19)) %>%
    pivot_longer(
    cols = c("cumulative_incidence_2014","cumulative_incidence_2016"),
    names_to = "year2",
    values_to = "cumulative_incidence"
  ) %>% mutate(year2=str_sub(year2, 22,25))
```

But the problem is that I cannot create one col: "year", and put the same year value from two different vars within the same ea_no. Now the output has two year cols (year and year2) since I just simply run twice pivot long code. The idea output like this:

```
ea_no.  year.   cumulative_incidence.  incidence
1.       2012.    xxx                    xxxx
2.       2014.     na                    xxxx
3.       2016      xxx                   xxxx
```

And my current code's output is like:

```
ea_no.  year.   cumulative_incidence.   year2  incidence
1.       2012.    xxx                    2012      xxxx
1.                 na                    2014.     xxxx
2.       2016      xxx                   na         na     
2.                                       2012      xxxx
3.       2014.     na                    2012      xxxx
3.       2016      xxx                   2014      xxxx
```

Does someone help to figure out a solution? and btw, thanks for helping how to smartly subset the number of year from the var name (*Now I just use str_sub with fixed distance, but it cannot work for vars with different distance*)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming all your 'year' entries have a similar structure, you could use a regular expression (regex) looking for four digits in a row to trim the years down.  `"[0-9]{4}"`  - regarding the other aspect, can you make two sub-tables (one with the year and incidence data, one with the year and cumulative incidence data) then separately pivot each and join them on the year column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure if this what you need given that the desired output seems to be incomplete. The important point is using the `names_pattern` attribute; here you can define a regex pattern for the new columns, namely two capturing groups:

- `(incidence_cases|cumulative_incidence)`, which will match and split into columns all columns with `incidence_cases` OR with `cumulative_incidence`and
- `(\\d+)`, which will match and create a new column for `year`

Solution:

```
ea %>%
  select(matches("ea|incidence")) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("incidence"),
    names_to = c(".value", "year"),
    names_pattern = "(incidence_cases|cumulative_incidence)_?(\\d+)"
  )
# A tibble: 408 × 5
      ea_no ea_actual year  incidence_cases cumulative_incidence
      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 10499003 ""        2012         NA                         NA
 2 10499003 ""        2013         NA                         NA
 3 10499003 ""        2014         NA                         NA
 4 10499003 ""        2016         NA                         NA
 5 10499004 ""        2012         NA                         NA
 6 10499004 ""        2013         NA                         NA
 7 10499004 ""        2014         NA                         NA
 8 10499004 ""        2016         NA                         NA
 9 10499005 "RV01"    2012          0                         NA
10 10499005 "RV01"    2013          0.00726                   NA
```

Comment: `values_to ="incidence_cases"` could be removed as it is overwritten by the `".values"` argument in `names_to `, correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris Ruehlemann, that is exactly output I am looking for~~! Thanks for your explicit explanations too.

Comment: @Chris Ruehlemann, may I ask why do we need  "_?" in between names and (\\d+)?  Thanks~~~!

Comment: That's because you have `cumulative_incidence_2014` (with _) and `incidence2014` (without `_`). `_?` makes the underscore optional